# Placing divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place three divs side by side and 
fourth div in the next row. I used `float:left` and `width:33%`.
What else property I need to apply to achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/wdvpubau/

Edit: One more thing regarding the same css styles,
I made property **display:inline** within css `.divinline` , but there is no difference in rendering. I had learnt that display:block will occupy the entire row. Is it being overridden?

Comment: just remove all dots from classes in html markup:  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wdvpubau/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As rightly suggested by @Imran, you need to remove the `.` before the css class names while you use them in html. Try:

```css
.divinline{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:33%;

}
.maindiv{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">

     <div class="divinline"> <!-- here the class is class="divline" and not .divline -->
       HI
     </div>
     <div class="divinline">
       HI
     </div>
     <div class="divinline">
       HI
     </div>
     <div class="divinline">
       HI
     </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/nithin_krishnan/r0Lyydg8/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as below

```
<div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px">1</div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px">2</div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px">3</div>
<div style="float:left;width:100px">4</div>
</div>
```